# How to obtain transfer function of control diagram with Internal Model Control?

Tags: control-engineering, control-theory, transfer-function, robust-control

I want to design a robust control system using the internal model design specifications. The block diagram is the one shown below:

[image]

I am trying to obtain the transfer function $\ \frac{Y(s)}{R(s)} $ in order to acquire the characteristic polynomial of the closed loop system but for some reason I am stuck. This is what I have done so far:

$$ E_{a}(s) = R(s) - Y(s) $$

$$ U(s) = E_{a}(s)G_{c}(s) - KX(s) $$ ( $\ U(s) $: control input to the process $\ G(s) $)

$$ Y(s) = U(s)G(s) = E_{a}(s)G(s)G_{c}(s)-KX(s)G(s) $$

$\ $

$$ Y(s) = R(s)G(s)G_{c}(s) - Y(s)G(s)G_{c}(s) - KX(s)G(s) $$
$\  $

$$ Y(s) = \frac{G(s)[R(s)G_{c}(s)-KX(s)]}{1+G(s)G_{c}(s)} $$

From this point, I really don't know how to continue. Obviously the term that confuses me is $\ X(s) $. So, now how should I proceed and obtain the overall transfer function ?

Comment: Diadikasia. I love Greek :-)

Comment: Yes, I like Greek too  But what about the transfer function ? Any ideas ? :-)

Comment: There was a deleted answer: *"I think the problem is that you are not considering that X(s) = Y(s)."* It was deleted on obvious reasons, but maybe it helps a little bit.

Comment: Well $X(s)$ consists of the states of the system (position,velocity) and $Y(s)$ is just the output of the system which is position. I don’t think this is a correct approach.

Comment: Maybe you can make use of the knowledge of the internals of G(s) to write x(s) in terms of the input of G(s)

Comment: Well, what I just thought and came up with a solution is this: find the transfer function of the inner loop (simple feedback look with gain K at feedback path)), replace the inter loop with this transfer function and finally obtain the overall transfer function which is again a simple unity feedback closed loop system. Do you agree?

Comment: Sounds like the right approach, you just need to find a way to properly describe the signal x(s) into the gain K

Comment: The block diagram is actually very clumsy because two different edges leaving makes only sense in a conceptual sense, as soon as the math is involved, more information is needed to describe how x and y differ

Comment: Can’t I just replace the whole inner loop with its transfer function $H(s) = \frac{G(s)}{1+KG(s)}$ ?

Comment: But that would be the transfer function of an output feedback, we have a state feedback. I think you need to write the transfer function in some state space fashion, involving A, B, C and D, to describe how x and y differ. y = Cx, so your approach only works if C is filled with 1s. Is there no more info on the internals of G(s)?

Comment: I have the transfer function: $G(s) = \frac{b_0}{s^2+a_1s+a_2}$

Comment: Think I figured it out. Will check it and post it as solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after a while this is what I finally came up with. I have tested the results in simulation environment as well as on the real system and the produced control behaviour was what I expected. Firs of all, I rewrote the block diagram in the form shown below:

[image]

The whole procedure of the transfer function is shown below:

The state variables of the plant process are $\ x_1, \ x_2 $ and they are equal to:

$$ x_1 = y \rightarrow X_1(s) = Y(s) $$
$$ x_2 = \dot{y} \rightarrow X_2(s) = sY(s) - y(0) $$

Considering zero initial conditions, the transfer function of the inner loop is (simple feedback system):

$$ H(s) = \frac{G_p(s)}{1+k_1G_p(s)+sk_2G_p(s)} $$

And now it all comes down to the outer loop being again a simple feedback loop:

$$ T(s) = \frac{G_c(s)H(s)}{1+G_c(s)H(s)} $$